# bash command line to log txt file python script

Tags: python, bash

I'd like to log my input/output in a standard linux bash command line to some kind of output or text file. How would I go about doing this?

Best,
-T

Comment: Use the `logging` module, don't do this through the shell.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Unix command that has been around a long time called `script` that will create a subshell and log all input and output to a file.

```
$ script /tmp/foo.log
Script started, file is /tmp/foo.log                                                                                 
$ date       
Sun Apr 15 21:36:47 EDT 2018
$ exit
Script done, file is /tmp/foo.log
```

Now that you have exited the subshell, you are back at your original session of bash and can inspect the log file that was created.

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.log                                      
Script started on Sun 15 Apr 2018 09:36:40 PM PDT
$ date
Sun Apr 15 21:36:47 EDT 2018                                                                                         
$ exit                                                     

Script done on Sun 15 Apr 2018 09:36:48 PM PDT
$
```

Comment: `script` does not create a subshell, it creates a new interactive shell process which reads/writes terminal IO to its own streams.  Only a shell can create a subshell, since a subshell holds a copy of the original shell settings, even when they have not been exported.  Nevertheless, this is a good answer.

Comment: I would add that the OP should read `man script`  for caveats.